# Crystal Report print output shrink on dot matrix printers

Tags: crystal-reports

Hi I am having problem printing my crystal report on dot matrix printer. the output become shrank. I already check the page setup of my crystal report and it is set to a4 same with the printer setup. I am using SAP crystal report and my printer is Epson LX 310 and LX 300.

Comment: please set it to 'Generic' or 'No Printer' may solve your problem, and always cross checked it `*.txt` export  when designing dot matrix reports

Comment: @ArsalanKhan where do i see the 'Generic' or 'No Printer' on crystal report? thank you responding to my question

Comment: File -> Page Setup here you see Printer Setup

Comment: @ArsalanKhan Thank you my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

`File` -> `Page Setup` here you see Printer Setup,please set it to '`Generic`' or '`No Printer`' may solve your problem, and always cross checked it `*.txt` export when designing dot matrix reports